# Are system calls the only way to interact with the Linux kernel from user land?

Tags: linux, kernel, architecture, system-calls

Are there any other interfaces, e.g. the /proc filesystem?

Comment: Even `/proc` and `/sys` involve system calls in order to open, write and close files so I'm leaning towards a negatory on that one. I don't know for sure, so I'm not posting an answer, but anything I can think of would require a syscall be made at some point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Linux kernel syscall API is the the primary API (though hidden under libc, and rarely used directly by programmers), and most standard IPC mechanisms are heavily biased toward the *everything is a file* approach, which eliminates them here as they ultimately require read/write (and more) calls.

However, on most platforms (if you exclude all the system calls to get you there) there is a way: [VDSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938324/what-are-vdso-and-vsyscall). This is a mechanism where the kernel maps one (or more) slightly magic pages into each process (usually in the form of an ELF .so). You can see this as `linux-vdso.so` or similar with `ldd` or in `/proc/PID/maps`. This is effectively memory-mapped IPC between the kernel and a user process (albeit one-way in its current implementation).

It's used to speed up syscalls in general and was originally implemented ([`linux-gate.so`](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/08/linux-gate/)) to address x86 performance issues, but it may also contain kernel data and access functions. Calls like `getcpu()` and `gettimeofday()` may use these rather than making an *actual* syscall and a kernel context switch. The availability of these optimised calls is detected and enabled by the glibc startup code (subject to platform availability). Current implementations contain a (read-only) page of shared kernel variables known as the "VVAR" page which can be read directly.

You can check this by inspecting the output of `strace -e trace=clock_gettime date` to see if your `date` command makes any `clock_gettime()` syscalls, with a working VDSO it will not (the time will be read from the VVARS page by a function in the VDSO page, see [`arch/x86/vdso/vclock_gettime.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/vdso/vclock_gettime.c?v=3.14)).

There's a useful technical summary here: http://blog.tinola.com/?e=5 a more detailed tutorial: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/creating-vdso-colonels-other-chicken , and the man page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html

Comment: The linux kernel also has ringbuffer and "memory mapped" interfaces. Some that come to mind: io_uring_setup(2) in polling mode, set_robust_list(2). Maybe there are others too.

Answer (score 9):

No.

Trivial counter example, this will interact with the kernel:

```c
int main() {
    volatile char *silly = 0;
    *silly = 'a';
}
```

That'll call the kernel's page fault handler, ultimately resulting in your process getting a `SIGSEGV` (presuming the compiler doesn't "optimize" that code to do something other than the obvious, since that's undefined behavior by the C standard, make sure to compile with `-O0`)

Comment: That seems almost vacuous.  If we count hardware traps into the kernel, then a busy loop which just eats an entire time-slice counts as "interacting" with the kernel, doesn't it?

Comment: @BruceEdiger this causes a signal to be raised, which seems more interacting than the scheduling interrupt, which is mostly transparent to the process. It does as much as the kill syscall would...

Comment: Put `silly` as global variable and make it itself volatile as well, and no sane compiler will optimize it, because it cannot know whether `silly` will be mapped to a memory-mapped I/O region during linking, in which case reading silly may not recover the `0` previously stored in it, but might actually deliver a valid address.